# search form not displaying correct result

Tags: php, sql

I am new to creating a search form, below is my code for the search form:

```
<h2>Search</h2> 
 <form name="search" method="post" action="search_result2.php">
 Search for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
 <Select NAME="field">
 <Option VALUE="testA">A</option>
 <Option VALUE="testB">B</option>
 <Option VALUE="testC">C</option>
 <Option VALUE="testD">D</option>
 </Select>
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
 </form>
```

**UPDATED:** search_result2.php:

```
<?php
 //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
if (isset($_POST['searching']) && $_POST['searching'] == "yes") 
{ 
echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 
//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
if (empty($_POST['find'])) 
{ 
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
exit; 
} 
 
 // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
 mysql_connect("host", "username", "passw") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error()); 
 
 // We preform a bit of filtering 
 $find = strtoupper($_POST['find']); 
 $find = strip_tags($_POST['find']); 
 $find = trim ($_POST['find']); 
 $field = trim ($_POST['field'])
 
 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 
 
 
 //And we display the results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo $result['testA']; 
 echo " "; 
 echo $result['testB']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo $result['testC']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo $result['testD']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 } 
 
 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 
 
 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
 } 
 ?>
```

==========================
now what is happening is whether I put in a search string or not it will display the following messages, which is exactly my code for the search result,

```
Results:

    "; //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error if ($find == "") { echo "
    
    You forgot to enter a search term";
    exit;
    } // Otherwise we connect to our Database
    mysql_connect("host", "username", "passw") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("testdb") or die(mysql_error());
    // We preform a bit of filtering $find = strtoupper($find);
    $find = strip_tags($find);
    $find = trim ($find);
    //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'");
    //And we display the results
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
        echo $result['testA'];
        echo " ";
        echo $result['testB'];
        echo "    ";
        echo $result['testC'];
        echo "    ";
        echo $result['testD'];
        echo "    ";
        echo "  ";
    } //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); if ($anymatches == 0) { echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query
    
    "; } //And we remind them what they searched for echo "Searched For: " .$find; } ?>
```

Comment: Try `$find = strtoupper($_POST['find']);` and do the same for the other two using the `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: still getting the same result...

Comment: If short open tags are not "ON", then change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: You missed a semi-colon on the last line of code before line 26. It should read: `$field = trim($_POST['field']);`

Comment: yeah...i think ur right that fixed...just saw that too after i posted that question...lol...thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed use  `<?php`instead of `<?`

few other recommendations

```
if (isset($_POST['searching']) && $_POST['searching'] == "yes") 
{ 
echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
if (empty($_POST['find'])) 
{ 
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
exit; 
}
```

also suggest you strip tags on `$field`

Comment: im not getting the initial error anymore but im getting this: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Templates\search_result2.php on line 26`

Comment: and line 26 refers to this: `$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'");`

Comment: You missed a semi-colon on the last line of code before line 26. It should read: `$field = trim($_POST['field']);`

Answer (score 1):

don't use `<?` insted of use `<?php` [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) can be disabled at server.